# Does HERE Routing API take into account traffic data?

Tags: here-api

We are going to use HERE Routing API to calculate a route in bus mode with route shape. Our use case: we know coordinates of bus stops but we need route shape between them. Bus mode take into account taxi/bus restricted streets as well as streets reserved for exclusive taxi/bus access and this is exactly what we need. But also we need take into account traffic data (live or typical) for this route, for specified departureTime. Can we get this info by HERE Routing API? For example, as durationInTraffic of route like google does? If no, is there any other HERE api to get such info? We saw HERE Traffic API but it looks like it provide full info about some area to draw it on map, not for route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it takes if you pass departure time as request param, see https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/8.20.0/dev_guide/topics/use-cases/departure-time.html